# grammar of PDF 1.7. (BNF or variant)

Tags: pdf, grammar, bnf, ebnf

I'm looking for a grammar of PDF 1.7 (BNF or variant)

absolutely not googleable

Comment: Don't think of a PDF as a single file with a single grammar, think of it as a hierarchy of data (e.g. directory of files) and some of those data items can be described with BNF or variant. See: [PDF 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and notice all of the **Normative References** in section 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF is a binary format that is not context-free. In PDF for example you need to read and interpret the size of a binary stream before parsing the stream.

Example:

```
10 0 obj
<</Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 260
/Height 52
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/SMask 10 0 R
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 4570>> stream
--- insert binary data here ---
endstream
endobj
```

There is no way to tell if your binary data will contain the tokens `endstream` or `endobj` inside, so you have no other choice than reading the length of the stream before parsing it.

[BNF can only be used for context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), so it is not possible to construct a BNF grammar for PDF.

Take a look at the specification here:
[PDF Reference Document](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf)

Comment: Binary does not imply it can't have a grammar. If you look at the PDF spec, you will see that pretty much all constructs are 'printable', except binary literals (streams). Some people must have written a PDF parser, so my guess is there must be a grammar around...

Comment: @3D-Grabber: yms didn't say *'Binary files can't have a grammar.'* What he said was more of *'Context-free formats can't have a BNF grammar.'*

Comment: @pipitas: _'Binary files can't have a grammar.'_ That's basically what he said before he edited the answer and clarified. I get the point now.

Comment: @3D-Grabber: Ok, I didn't notice the editing history of the answer. Sorry.

Comment: This is old but nonetheless....could PDF's non context-free grammar be described as a stack of context-free grammars. For instance, the overall structure being one context-free grammar and then each component object becoming described with their own context-free grammar?

Comment: @George not all of it... the streams structure with encryption, compression and 100 different kinds of encodings is always going to be non context-free, but there are indeed certain portions that can be considered context-free. For example the content of a page or xobject, embedded javascript, embedded xml, some embedded font formats (not all since bitmaps are part of the mix), some custom functions for definning shadings and gradients (there is a proper name for this functions but I forgot now, the code is very similar to postscript). So, to some extent you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any *formal* specification of the PDF file format in the form of a grammar, BNF or not.

But I happen to know for sure that the ISO technical committee 171/SC2 which currently works on the specification of PDF-2.0 has an agenda topic of *"Updates from ad hoc committees: [...] iv. File format syntax for validating PDF files (L. Rosenthol)"* for its next face to face meeting taking place in Berlin, Sept 11-12 2012. -- Which agenda item I take as *"some more people seem to be interested in a more formal description of the PDF syntax"*... :-)

Leonard Rosenthol is an Adobe PDF higher-up, and he frequently answers questions in the Adobe user forums. Maybe it is a good idea to ask a question there? Chances are, there you'll get a better answer than here.